# -Err_04149 not a valid escape value in ldap search

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query, apache-directory

I am using Apache directory studio  to see LDAP tree structure. In that, I am doing basic search operation to display all sAMAccountNames by below search filter

```
(sAMAccountName = * )
```

and this search successfully return all object which have sAMAccountName when I escape the special character by `\\2a` (now my search is `(sAMAccountName = \\2a)` ) and do the search which returns error like `"Error while performing search -Err_04149 not a valid escape value"`. I expect zero results found message but got error.

`(sAMAccountName = \\2a)` is not a valid search in Ldap?

Comment: Try No spaces (sAMMAccountName=*) ?

Comment: @jwilleke. Thanks for comment  but i get proper results for expression (sAMAccountName = * ). when I try with expression (sAMAccountName = \\2a) I'm getting error.  So my question is why \\2a is not a valid expression

Answer (score 1):

In Apache directory studio `\\2a` is not a valid expression. `\2a` is enough expression for apache directory studion ldap search.